# How To Set Default Window Mode to Full Screen in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3, winui

```cs
namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        AppWindow m_appWindow;
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            m_appWindow = GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow();
        }
               
        private AppWindow GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow()
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
            WindowId myWndId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
                    
            return AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);
        }

        private void SwitchPresenter_FullScreen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            m_appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
        }  
    }
}
```

SwitchPresenter_FullScreen function is works but how can i set my app's default window mode to full screen? Can i call SwitchPresenter_FullScreen while app starting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Don't call `SwitchPresenter_FullScreen` directly. This method is for your UI controls (like `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton`).

Just add this line to your `MainWindow` constructor.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    m_appWindow = GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow();
    m_appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);  // This line
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Window still becomes normal, not full screen.

Comment: That's weird. I did create a blank project and just applied your code for this and worked. Are you sure you are not doing anything related anywhere else?

Comment: I did create a blank project for testing and it didn't work. I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: I did upgrade NuGet Packages(Windows APP SDK 1.0.3 to 1.1.3) and it's works now!